# java 7 installation in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, java

I try to install jdk1.7.0_79 in ubuntu 14.04
First I download jdk1.7.0_79 Zip File.Then extact file and put it into download folder.

Then I create a directory like this

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
```

Then move jdk1.7.0_11 into the `/usr/lib/jvm`

```
sudo mv /Downloads/jdk1.7.0_79 /usr/lib/jvm
```

Then install file into followng step

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javac"
```

---

This similar to both javac and javaws installation.
Then I try

```
computerlabug@computerlab:/usr/bin$ java -version 
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

And Configure as follows

```
computerlabug@computerlab:/usr/bin$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

```
  Selection    Path                                Priority   Status 
------------------------------------------------------------ 

* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java    2         auto mode 

  1            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/bin//java   1         manual mode 

  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java    2         manual mode 

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

This is similar to javac and javaws

Then check java -version

```
computerlabug@computerlab:/usr/bin$ java -version 
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory**
```

What I do please explain step by step

Comment: Is it important to install this specific java version?

Comment: yes.I chech /usr/bin dirctory but it has java,javac and javaws file.

Comment: But the link to java is wrong.

Comment: how to resolve this linkage error

Comment: Look into my answer. I added the solution.

Comment: I added priority to fix the commands.

Comment: how to add priority and where we add priority

Comment: Just run the commands at the end of my answer and java will work.

Comment: Please do not post this kind of things to comments. [edit] your question instead.

Comment: And please add output of `update-alternatives --list java` and `ls /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in the `update-alternatives` command.

It should be

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin/java" 1
```

You've missed `jre`

Your `javac` command seem to be OK.

But the `javaws` is also

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin/javaws" 1
```

**To fix it run**

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javaws
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javac
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/bin/javaws" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javac" 1
```

Comment: It is  applied both javac and javaws also.is it true

Comment: No, for javac it is OK. I will add to answer.

Comment: i should use these commands sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javaws
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all javac in which directory either /usr/lib/jvm or /usr/bin

Comment: Yes, run all these commands.

Comment: Be careful with the last one, I just fixed a typo.

Comment: which directory i use these commands either  /usr/lib/jvm or /usr/bin

Comment: It does not matter from where you run these commands. Just run them one by one in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Why not install it the easy way?

This method install Java JDK, JRE and the Java browser plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

To check if the installation worked, enter the following command:

```
java -version
```